# What's the difference between `bl_rna` and `rna_type`?

Tags: python, properties

The code for accessing properties via `bl_rna` and `rna_type` gives the same result.

```
import bpy

obj = #blah blah any random object bpy.data.node_groups["Aaa"].nodes["Bbb"]

for pr in obj.bl_rna.properties:
    print(pr)

for pr in obj.rna_type.properties:
    print(pr)
```

What is the difference between them?

Comment: I don't think there's a difference.. it's just inherited from different structures. If you try something like ```obj.bl_rna == obj.rna_type``` the result should be ```true```.

Comment: @Secrop can you elaborate on "inherited from different structures"? Do you know which these structures are? `bl_rna` and `rna_type` seem to always point to the same object from my tests, but if they are from different structures it may be possible there is a case where they indeed point to different objects?

Comment: @taiyo It may be some legacy thing.. ```rna_type``` is a direct representation of the C structure described in the ```rna_types.c```, and ```bl_rna``` is something that is mainly created for the Python API. It may just be a way to allow a python custom data structure to behave as a C structure... but it is as old as I can remember, and probably it's just kept for compatibility reasons.